# AngularJS 1.0.7: limitto filter not working

Tags: angularjs

any reason why a simple `{{item.description | limitTo: 10}}` does not work in Angular1.0.7? It shows the whole description. No errors in the console.

In html page:

```
...
<hr class="no-margin-top" />
<div class="row-fluid custom-row-margin-20">
    <div class="span12 boat-description">{{boat.description | limitTo: 40}}</div>
</div>
...
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Why in hell are you using angular 1.0.7 in the first place? It's more than 4 years old. There have been dozens of releases, fixing hundreds of bugs since then. The current version is 1.6.6.

Comment: There is no post that I write, where I got one smart comment  like yours providing zero value... And you all say this as it would be just a click to migrate to the latest version. I developed my angular web app probably three years ago, when the latest version was 1.0.7. As you can imagine, we don´t have time to migrate our webapp each time Angular release a new version.

Comment: @Rober you'd be surprised by the number of people asking questions similar to yours, but starting a new project. I still think that staying on a version for 4 years is a very bad idea, and migrating very often is quite easy, given that every release comes with a changelog listing the breaking changes. I've done it quite a lot myself.

Comment: Believe me, I would love to migrate! I wish I had the time to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original `limitTo` filter only supported arrays.  Support for strings was added in Angular 1.1.12 [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#112-tofu-animation-2013-01-22).

Prior to Angular 1.1.12, it was necessary to manually cut a string.  An example of a custom directive to do this was included in the bug tracker;  I'll include it here (note, not written by me, and not fully tested).

```
/**
 * Usage:
 *   {{some_text | cut:true:100:' ...'}}
 * Options:
 *   - wordwise (boolean) - if true, cut only by words bounds,
 *   - max (integer) - max length of the text, cut to this number of chars,
 *   - tail (string, default: '&nbsp;&hellip;') - add this string to the input
 *     string if the string was cut.
 */
.filter('cut', function () {
    return function (value, wordwise, max, tail) {
        if (!value) return '';

        max = parseInt(max, 10);
        if (!max) return value;
        if (value.length <= max) return value;

        value = value.substr(0, max);
        if (wordwise) {
            var lastspace = value.lastIndexOf(' ');
            if (lastspace != -1) {
                value = value.substr(0, lastspace);
            }
        }

        return value + (tail || ' …');
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I will recommend to use the latest version of angularjs, but still it should work with 1.0.7 as well

**DEMO**

```js
var app= angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.boat ={};
  $scope.boat.description ="The length of the returned array or string. If the limit number is positive, limit number of items from the beginning of the source array/string are copied. If the number is negative, limit number of items from the end of the source array/string are copied. The limit will be trimmed if it exceeds array.length. If limit is undefined, the input will be returned unchanged.";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<hr class="no-margin-top" />
<div class="row-fluid custom-row-margin-20">
    <div class="span12 boat-description">{{boat.description | limitTo: 40}}</div>
</div>
</body>
```

**EDIT**

With angular 1.0.7, the **`limitTo`** filter is work with only Array. For your requirement,you need to implement custom filter.

```
.filter("limitToCustom",function(){
    return function(actual,number){
        console.log(number)
        var arrData = actual.split("");
        return  actualData.slice(-number);
    }
});
```

and in **`HTML`**

```
<h1>Hello {{boat.description |limitToCustom : 40 }}!</h1>
```

Comment: "it should work with 1.0.7"... This doesn't really answer the question.  Recommending a newer version *might* be a reasonable response, but it still doesn't really address the issue, and there may be some specific reason that the OP is required to use the specific version they are using.

Comment: Thanks!! @Claies It´s really easier to say migrate! Instead to try to fix the problem.

Comment: @sajeetharan which version are you using in your example? 1.2.23? If so, sorry not ok.

Comment: @Rober yes you are right ! it does not work with 1.0.7 for strings, it works for integers though http://jsfiddle.net/y04ubbhd/

Comment: Wow, quite awesome. Thanks! I give the OK to @Claies because I think his answer is more complete. But yours is of course ok as well.

Comment: @Rober You can simplify as above

Answer (score -2):

Please use angular js 1.2.10. 
**DEMO**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<div class="row-fluid custom-row-margin-20">
    <div class="span12 boat-description">{{boat.description | limitTo: 50}}</div>
</div>  
</div>

<script>
var app= angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.boat ={};
  $scope.boat.description ="The length of the returned array or string. If the limit number is positive, limit number of items from the beginning of the source array/string are copied. If the number is negative, limit number of items from the end of the source array/string are copied. The limit will be trimmed if it exceeds array.length. If limit is undefined, the input will be returned unchanged.";
});
</script>
```